# Winsock 2 portability

Tags: c++, winsock, portability

I'm about to develop some sockets related stuff in C++ and would like the software to be as portable between Windows and Linux as possible right from the start (making it portable later is tricky.)

I've looked at different libraries, there is one for C++ from [alhem.net](http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/) and of course there is boost::asio. boost::asio looks very promising but would be a very big dependency for applications this small.

Is it even worth writing the stuff myself or should I just use a library? If I do it myself what would be the main pitfalls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Winsocks aren't very compatible with Posix sockets:

- In Winsocks a socket is of type `SOCKET`. On Posix it's simply a file descriptor (`int`), on which you can perform normal `read()` and `write()` calls.
- They don't return errors the same way.
- They don't support some options on `recv()` and `send()`.
- You have to initialize and unitialize the Winsocks library with two specials functions.
- I don't think you can close Windows sockets with `shutdown()` or `close()`. It's something like `closesocket()` instead.

There must be more differences, but that's what I can remember right now. If you want portability with Winsocks, you'll have a small library for closing a socket, printing an error message and so on.

I'd probably go with `boost::asio`, personnally (I've never used it, though).

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I do. boost::asio has an ICMP interface too which is very nice so currently it looks like I'll use that.

Comment: shutdown() is a valid function for Windows sockets.  Are you correct that closesocket() needs to be used, though.

Comment: closesocket is just the windows version of close -- so that they didn't have to overload the close function. You don't HAVE to close a file/socket, but if you don't, you may get data loss. WSAGetLastError is just the windows function to get errno, since the windows API didn't support errno the same way. And for sockets, POSIX supports "send" and "recv" versions of read and write.

Answer (score 5):

I've developed a few portable wrappers around sockets. Make sure you don't go down the crappy lane of no return that is constituted of WinSock2 events. Other than that, as I see it, the biggest differences are:

- to start networking in Windows, you need to call `::WSAStartup()`, to shut it down in Windows, run `::WSACleanup()`; in Linux do nothing,
- `close()` in Linux is `closesocket()` in Windows,
- default buffer sizes differ between both drivers and operating systems, so make sure to set them using `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF`,
- SO_REUSEADDR steals the address on Windows, allows frequent re-opening on Linux; you'd probably only want to use this flag in Linux,
- making a socket non-blocking uses `::ioctlsocket()` in Windows, `::fcntl()` in Linux,
- the header files are different, `<sys/socket.h>` and friends in Linux, `<WinSock.h>` in Windows,
- to go portable, the easiest way is probably to use `::select()` to wait for data to arrive,
- `fd_set`s are totally different on Windows/Linux; this is only relevant if you need to optimize initialization of `fd_set`s, such as when adding/removing arbitrary sockets,
- in Windows, any thread hanging on the socket is released with an error code when the socket is closed, in Linux the thread remains waiting. If the thread is blocking the socket with for instance `::recvfrom()`, you might consider using `::sendto()` to release the stalling thread under Linux.

Everything else I ever needed just worked out of the låda.

Comment: Very useful advice. Tackar och bugar ;).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the "Adaptive Communications Environment" (ACE) library:
[(ACE Home Page)](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html)
It provides some nice abstractions and a lot of flexibility all rolled up in a portable library that supports Windows, MacOS and Linux.
It has a bit of a steep learning curve, but I got very good value from it.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd use boost::asio as a first preference. If you really want to get down and dirty with the sockets API, you can use the standard BSD-style sockets API on both Windows and Linux - it's just that on Windows you'll have to link to (and initialize) Winsock2, whereas on Linux you won't have a separate library to link against.

Answer (score 1):

How much socket stuff will you be using? I've done several apps where the socket stuff was pretty high level (open, read, write), and worked perfectly from Windows to Linux. If it's more than that - go with boost.

Comment: At first, it would be very low level, like open a connection, write something, read, quit. It could probably grow to include Http-stuff though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this... http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-sockets/

Comment: Seems quite useful. Thanks mate. It seems rather old though, last updated 2003? But maybe it still works well.